# Splitting a file incrementally

Tags: awk, sed, split

I would like to split a file incrementally. My file looks like:

```
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_1" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    v   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    ^   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_2" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    ^   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    v   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   v   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   v   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   v   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    v   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_3" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    v   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U782/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U781/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U632/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX0_LVT)
"U999/Y"    ^   ;   //  (NAND4X0_LVT)
"U1000/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND2X0_LVT)
"U1006/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND4X0_LVT)
"U1007/Y"   ^   ;   //  (AND4X1_LVT)
"prope_ff_q_reg_0_/D"   ^   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
.
.
.
```

I would like to have files which have "path" incrementally. 
The 1st file has the 1st path. The 2nd file has the 1st and 2nd paths. The 3rd file has the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd paths. This incremental splitting will be continued the end of the original file. (upto n).

P1:

```
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_1" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    v   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    ^   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
```

P2:

```
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_1" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    v   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    ^   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_2" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    ^   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    v   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   v   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   v   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   v   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    v   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
```

P3:

```
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_1" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    v   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   ^   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    ^   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_2" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    ^   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U870/Y"    v   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U873/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX1_LVT)
"U872/Y"    v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1045/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1046/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND3X0_LVT)
"U1063/Y"   v   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1092/Y"   v   ;   //  (OR3X1_LVT)
"U1095/Y"   v   ;   //  (OA21X1_LVT)
"illinste_ff_q_reg_0_/D"    v   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
$path {
$name "path_sparc_ifu_dec_3" ;
$transition {
"dtu_inst_d[22]"    v   ;   //  (in)
"U622/Y"    ^   ;   //  (INVX16_LVT)
"U782/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U781/Y"    ^   ;   //  (AND2X1_LVT)
"U632/Y"    v   ;   //  (INVX0_LVT)
"U999/Y"    ^   ;   //  (NAND4X0_LVT)
"U1000/Y"   v   ;   //  (NAND2X0_LVT)
"U1006/Y"   ^   ;   //  (NAND4X0_LVT)
"U1007/Y"   ^   ;   //  (AND4X1_LVT)
"prope_ff_q_reg_0_/D"   ^   ;   //  (DFFX1_LVT)
}
}
```

Could you let me know how to do this job? Any language (sed,awk,grep) are okay to me.

Best,

Jaeyoung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk`. You can play with the record separator, like this:

```
awk '{file="P"NR".txt";print > file;close(file)}' RS='}\n}\n' ORS='}\n}\n' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`gawk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS="\n}\n}" 'NR==1{term=RT}
                           {a[NR]=$0}
           END{for(i=1;i<NR;i++) 
                  for(k=1;k<=i;k++) 
                     print a[k] term > FILENAME"_"i}' file
```